# Phonegap: get the filesize of captured audio file

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am using phonegap to build an iPhone application. I recorded the file using the following  code.

navigator.device.capture.captureAudio( 
   captureSuccess, captureError
);

How can i get the file size of this captured audio file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The captureSuccess method of navigator.device.capture.captureAudio( captureSuccess, captureError ) will be called with an array of [MediaFile](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile) objects which has the size parameter.

```
function captureSuccess(audioFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = audioFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        console.log("Name = " + audioFiles[i].name);
        console.log("Path = " + audioFiles[i].fullPath);
        console.log("Type = " + audioFiles[i].type);
        console.log("Size = " + audioFiles[i].size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method to capture the audio,

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio( 
    CaptureCB captureSuccess, CaptureErrorCB captureError,  [CaptureAudioOptions options]
);
```

Example:

```
// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start audio capture
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});
```

When the capture operation is finished, it will invoke the **CaptureCB** callback with an array of **MediaFile** objects describing each captured audio clip file.
You will get the size of the audio using the size property.

Please check the link for further reference [Audio capture using phone gap example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFile)